# iOS toolkit/framework/component for building news like app

Tags: iphone, ios, rss

Is there some-kind of open-source (or commercial) toolkit, framework or iOS component that would simplify process of making iPhone app for news-like website?

I know there are on-line services that create a native iPhone app from your blog (Wordpress, Blogger, ...), but we have a custom-build news site and we need a native iPhone app. Is there something cool to begin with, some kind of framework or toolkit that would offer you a basic setup like data fetching, caching, categorizing and common UI in terms of native iOS UIKit elements? Or is the only way to go do-it-yourself-from-beginning-to-the-end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there are a couple of SDKs that will allow you to create full Apps using html, css and javascript.

- Phonegap (http://phonegap.com/)
- Cordova (http://cordova.apache.org/)

Comment: My wild guess: `but we have a custom-build news site and we need a native iPhone app` and now look at what you purposed.

Comment: But... these systems convert html/css/javascript into native code/components... Thank you anyway

Comment: You have a Native App with a `UIWebView`. That's what you have. The good part is cross platform.

Comment: Phonegap definitely looks interesting. Thanks for sharing.